# JQuery fadeIn, fadeOut div

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

I have a button ("login_button"). Every time I click the button I want a DIV ("login_cont") to appear. And after, if I click anywhere else on the page I want this DIV disappear again.

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login_button').click(function(e){
    $('#login_cont').fadeIn();
});
$(document).click(function(e){
    $('#login_cont').fadeOut();
});
});
```

This looks good to me (I'm new at this). 
But. Every time I click on the button, the div appears but then also disappears in less than a second... why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the speed of fading with a number of milliseconds or just by calling it "slow":

```
$('#login_button').click(function(e){
    $('#login_cont').fadeIn(3000);
    return false;
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    $('#login_cont').fadeOut('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Update (above): Return false to prevent default click action if the default click will submit.

Comment: the speed is not the problem, I don't want it to fadeOut until I click somewhere else on the page...

Comment: I misunderstood what you were saying. You can return false to prevent default behavior of the click.

Answer (score 0):

stop the click event from propagating when you click the login button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#login_button').click(function(event){
                event.stopPropagation()
                $('#login_cont').fadeIn();
            });

            $(document).click(function(e){
                $('#login_cont').fadeOut();
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the document and #login_cont both being clicked (#login_cont is part of document)

You can fix this by changing

```
$(document).click(function(e){
                $('#login_cont').fadeOut('slow');
            });
```

to

```
$('#login_cont').onblur(function(e){
                $('#login_cont').fadeOut('slow');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the two event are fired in the same time you need to stopPropagation :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#login_button').click(function(e){
                    $('#login_cont').fadeIn();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });

                $(document).click(function(e){
                    $('#login_cont').fadeOut();
                });
});
```